# Viewing algebraic varieties as Homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, And let $V(\mathfrak{a})$ be the algebraic variety generated by the ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. I have read that we can identify $V(\mathfrak{a})$ as

$V(\mathfrak{a})=\text{Hom}_{k-alg}( k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/ \mathfrak{a} , k)$.

But I don't see how. I know that the points of $V(\mathfrak{a})$ is in bijection with the maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/ \mathfrak{a}$ by Hilbert's Nullstellenstaz, but I don't see how to view it as $k$-algebra homomorphism.

Comment: The kernal of a morphisn $k[x]/a \to k$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Adding to the above comment: An algebra homomorphism from a polynomial algebra is uniquely determined by where it sends the variables. Taking a quotient then introduces a suitable requirement that certain combinations of these values are 0.

Comment: Hi can you explain more I'm still a bit confused..

Comment: I remember you that the homomorphism of $\mathbb{K}$-algebras send the units in the units; so the homomorphism from $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ to $\mathbb{K}$ are all "onto". From all this, using the comment of @Youngsu, you have the statement; for exact, $V(\mathfrak{a})$ is in bijection with the set $Hom_{\mathbb{K}-alg}(\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a},\mathbb{K})$.